# Weird issue with $_FILES['']

Tags: php, file, file-upload, csv

Hey guys I noticed when I switched my provider to a dedicated server (Winhost to MediaTemple) that my file uploading system no longer works because it can't read the file sent in for some reason.  So I put aside a tester to figure out why and I used:

```
<form method="post" action="./readtest.php">
        <div>
            <span>Enter Name of First Name Column: </span><input name="firstname" class="Rfirstname-input" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Enter .csv File: </span><input type="file" name="csvfile" value="" />
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="submit" class="Rsubmit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

than:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['firstname'];
var_dump($_FILES['csvfile']);
?>
```

Now the firstname post will print out but the dumping of the files is null (I upload .csv files).  Now the weird part, when I change the $_FILES to $_POST - it actually prints out the name of the file, so it is actually going in yet not reading it?  I tried for other files to.....I don't know if it is something in my .ini file for php or what but I could use the help!

David Biga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this answer:[What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

You are missing the enctype on your  `<form>`

Comment: Do I need to var_dump($_POST...) than? or keep it as file

Comment: Did you refreshed the html page? You might test the result printing $_FILES: print_r($_FILES);

Comment: Yes....that printed the results but for my main function it does not seem to be working

Comment: Hey so I created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DrEJB/1/ - if you could check it out, I am having that issue where I am unable to open to store the values of the inside of the .csv file and it seems to just kick me out...so check it out and let me know please

Answer (score 1):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>`.